# 'int' object has no attribute 'save' in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, integer

I have a value in a database on phpmyadmin and I want to  change this value by a new calculated value. The function save() doesn't work and the error tells me that it's because it's an interger. I don't know how to solve this problem.

```
def DeleteBulle (request, id_bulle):

        #suppression de la bulle par l'id
        id_bulle
        param = Bulles.objects.get(pk=id_bulle)
        #param.delete()

        #adaptation du champ "nombre de bulle" dans la table "site"
        site=param.id_site
        print('site', site)
        compte=Bulles.objects.filter(id_site=site).count()
        print('nombre bulle avec site identique', compte)
        nbrbulle=Bulles.objects.get(pk=id_bulle).id_site.nombre_bulles
        nbrbulle=compte
        nbrbulle.save()
        
        #réussite
        print("Bulle supprimée")

        return redirect('api_bulles_frontend')
```

Models :

```
class Site(models.Model):
id_site = models.AutoField(
    db_column="Id_site", primary_key=True
)  # Field name made lowercase.
nom = models.CharField(
    db_column="Nom", max_length=100
)  # Field name made lowercase.
vitesse_b = models.FloatField(db_column="Vitesse_b")  # Field name made lowercase.
vitesse_c = models.FloatField(db_column="Vitesse_c")  # Field name made lowercase.
ecart_type_b = models.FloatField(
    db_column="Ecart_type_b"
)  # Field name made lowercase.
ecart_type_c = models.FloatField(
    db_column="Ecart_type_c"
)  # Field name made lowercase.
type_site = models.CharField(
    db_column="Type_site", max_length=20
)  # Field name made lowercase.
longitude = models.FloatField(db_column="Longitude")  # Field name made lowercase.
latitude = models.FloatField(db_column="Latitude")  # Field name made lowercase.
nombre_bulles = models.IntegerField(db_column="Nombre_bulles")
date_vidange = models.DateField(
    db_column="Date_vidange"
)  # Field name made lowercase.
#trajet = models.ManyToManyField(Trajet, related_name='site_moi')

class Meta:
    db_table = "site"


class Bulles(models.Model):
id_bulle = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
num_bulle = models.CharField(max_length=20)
type_bulle = models.CharField(max_length=20)
colories = models.CharField(max_length=20)
latitude = models.FloatField()
longitude = models.FloatField()
date_vidange = models.DateField(
    db_column="date_vidange"
) 
id_depot = models.ForeignKey(
    "Depot", on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column="id_depot"
)
id_site = models.ForeignKey(
    "Site",related_name='bul', on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column="Id_site"
)  
class Meta:
    db_table = "bulles"
```

I don't know how to solve this problem. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please share the relevant models...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You're trying to call save on integer eg.`nbrbulle=compte` where `compte` is count of `Bulles` and int object don't have any method named as `save()`

Comment: @Community I count the number of bulles with the same Id_site and then I want to update in the table "site"  the "nombre_bulles" with the value calculated previously.

Comment: `site.nombre_bulles = compte` amd then `site.save()`? Why are you even storing the count in a field anyway? You can get it anytime you need using an aggregation.

Comment: @AnkitTiwari Ok so how an I update this value ?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I need to update the value in my database because I'm using this column of the database in other parts of the code, treated by other person

Comment: @lsn: well, it is not good to introduce duplicated data: one can use `.annotate(..)` to obtain the number of related items. This is more robust: if here you change for example the `id_site` of a `Bulle`, then it will need to update two counts, and it thus makes the logic a lot more complicated.

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP? Django is Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save the `site` object with the updated item, not update the `nombre_bulles`, which is just an integer:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods


@require_http_methods(['POST', 'DELETE'])
def DeleteBulle(request, id_bulle):
    bulle = get_object_or_404(Bulles, pk=id_bulle)
    site = param.id_site
    bulle.delete()
    site.nombre_bulles = site.bul.count()
    site.save(update_fields=['nombre_bulles'])
    return redirect('api_bulles_frontend')
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Bulles` instead of <s>`Bulle`</s>.

---

> **Note**: Normally one does not add a prefix `id_…` to a `ForeignKey` field, since Django
> will automatically add a "twin" field with an `…_id` suffix. Therefore it should
> be `site`, instead of <s>`id_site`</s>.

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

---

> **Note**: One can use the [**`@require_POST`** decorator <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.http.require_POST)
> to restrict the view to only be accessible for a POST request.